# XPath crashes on getAttribute in PHP

Tags: php, xpath

here's a XML snippet from my .XML file

```
< products >  
< product no="AP1126S-07" name=""Clergoux" necktie set" >  
< stocks >  
< stock name="navi_central" value="149"/ >  
< stock name="navi_arrive" value="" date=""/ >  
< /stocks >  
< /product >
```

here's my code

```
$xmlString = 'anda_xml_export2_mini.php.xml';
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->load($xmlString);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$sku = 'AP1123-07';

$my_stock = $xpath->query("/products/product[@no='".$sku."']/stocks/stock");

echo $my_stock->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
```

the code above is fine, it's working, in my little php testing file.

But the problem appears when I incorporate the code in my 600K **index.php** file,
which hosts the whole frontpage side of my company's website.

I checked in my index.php file with flags and it seems that the whole code crashes / stops working when I echo the **getAttribute** thing for **'value'**, which is the last line of my code snippet here.

any help would be appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: How many items are in $my_stock result? What error message is displayed/written to the log file? I'm assuming that the initialization is done at the top so are $doc and $xpath still what you'd expect?
Finally, did you use a variable named $my_stock as a pointer elsewhere in the code? If so, change its name and see what happens.

Comment: Mike, i added a snippet from my .XML file.....$doc and $xpath are initialized fine, $my_stock is not present anywhere else in the code....

Comment: i did a var_dump($my_stock) and it says object(DOMNodeList)#4 (0) { }

Comment: ....managed to read my XML finally with XMLReader (the Java style one) which is real fast and flexible for your basic name, value/attribute read. Thanks all!

Comment: I was thinking more of $my_stock->length, to see if you actually have any nodes returned.